# Coming from Android XML layouts, how to place web page elements in XHTML?

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm primarily an Android developer, but I'm very interested in creating web pages in XHTML using CSS for styling those pages. I'd like to make a simple web page layout comprised of three rows with the middle row having three columns. In Android XML I'd accomplish that like so (roughly):

```
<LinearLayout orientation:vertical> (parent)
----<LinearLayout orientation: horizontal>
----<LinearLayout orientation: horizontal>
--------<LinearLayout orientation: vertical>
--------<LinearLayout orientation: vertical>
--------<LinearLayout orientation: vertical>
----<LinearLayout orientation: horizontal>
```

That'd create a layout that looks something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|                                             |
-----------------------------------------------
|             |                   |           |
-----------------------------------------------
|                                             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I'm still a bit new to XHTML and CSS (though I have the fundamentals down) and while I'm a pretty quick learner, I haven't found any tutorials on layout designs for web pages aimed at an Android developer. If anyone could please explain a good way to achieve the layout I'm going for, I'd greatly appreciate it.

TLDR: How do I make a web site layout consisting of three rows, with the middle row having three columns, using XHTML and/or CSS?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using XHTML.  HTML5 is clearly the way things are going.

Comment: I can appreciate where you're coming from, but I'd much rather learn web site development coming from a format I'm familiar with (XHTML), then switch to HTML5 once I feel comfortable with the basics.

Comment: There's very little difference between the two, especially from the beginner's perspective, and any time you spend dealing with the specifics of XHTML is frankly wasted.

Comment: Very well, in that case, do you have any advice on how to achieve what I listed above using HTML5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably something you should learn through tutorials, but here's an approximation of what you asked for.  http://jsfiddle.net/7LYhu/

#### HTML

```
<div class="row"> Row
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  Column
    </div>
  <div class="col">
      Column
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      Column
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    Row
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
.row {
      width: 80%;
      background: gray;
      text-align: center;
    }
.col {
      width: 33.3%;
      float: left;
      background: orange;
}​
```

Comment: This is not ideal. If you add a col, you'll need to change the css as well :( In android, this will be automatic.